# Twig I can include code in CSS?

Tags: css, symfony, twig

I have this code currently does not work, is there any alternative to it?

```
<ul class="sub">
 {% for key, c in categori %}
     <style>
         #nav.{{c.id}}:hover
         {
           background-color: #{{c.color}};
         }
     </style>
        <li class="{{c.id}}">
            <a href="{{ path('categoria', {'id': c.id} )}}">{{ c.nombre }}
....
```

I have the problem as in # nav. {{c.id}}

ow.ly/i/3vwNp this is the example

Thanks!

Comment: `this code currently does not work`: what do you mean?

Comment: I have a list of categories, and each of them has a background color that picks up a database, then I have to assign each list and I can not think how to do it, this background color is produced when located mouse over it.

Comment: I still don't get it...do you have an example of what you want to do?

Comment: http://ow.ly/i/3vwNp this is the example

Answer (score 2):

The way your CSS is written, it expects the element with the class `{{ c.id }}` (as interpreted by the Twig parser) to be on the same element with the id `nav`, e.g.

`<li id="nav" class="{{ c.id }}">...</li>`

You really shouldn't have more than one element on a page with the same `id` attribute, strange things happen with JavaScript particularly when you do.

Instead of trying to programmatically define your `{{ c.id }}` in the style though, why not do something like this?

```
<style>
  #nav .item:hover
  {
    background-color: #{{c.color}};
  }
</style>
...
<ul id="nav" class="sub">
{% for key, c in categori %}
  <li class="item {{c.id}}"><a href="{{ path('categoria', {'id': c.id} )}}">{{ c.nombre }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You really should only be placing CSS in `<style>` tags at the top of the document any way, or as better practice teasing them out to `.css` resource files to include.

Comment: ow.ly/i/3vwNp this is the example

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely work:

```
<ul class="sub">
{% for c in categori %}
  <style>
     .element{{c.id}} a:hover { background-color: #{{c.color}}; }
  </style>
  <li class="element{{c.id}}">
    <a href="{{ path('categoria', {'id': c.id} )}}">{{ c.nombre }}
...
```

But it's recommended to separate your CSS rules from HTML and move all your predefined element classes to external CSS asset.

Comment: @RamónDevesa Could you please provide a generated HTML so I can test it?